# In DynamoDB in the AWS Mobile Hub, why is there no option for creating local secondary indexes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-mobilehub

I am creating an app and using AWS's mobile hub. For some reason there is no option to create a local secondary index. I found on their forums from 2013 someone saying this is purposely not included because it is not best practice. Why would this be the case? How can I sort my data in different ways without using scans? Say I want to sort user posts by rating and by date. Is it better to create two global secondary indexes with the same primary key and different sort keys?

Answer (score 0):

"Is it better to create two global secondary indexes with the same primary key and different sort keys?" That is correct.